# Is it possible to share a link with a picture to facebook in an Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am sharing a picture generated by my Android app to Facebook  through this code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com");

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmapLogoPhoto)
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .setContentUrl(uri)

                .build();
```

It just shares the picture, though... no link...  I want to share a picture with a link that drives the user to my app's url (the above code is an example... it would be another url)... is it possible?

I am trying to do this as there is no open graph action that suits to my app's action...and now the custom action is deprecated... and additionally the graph api "picture" parameter that used to allow sharing pictures from the application is also deprecated, now it accepts only pictures from an url.

How can I share a picture that is generated in my app with a link that drives the user to my app? Is it possible?

Comment: You need to make the link you are sharing provide the image URL via OG meta tags, that is the only way.